# Fancy box will not work

Tags: fancybox-2

here is my codepen: 
`

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function() { 
   $(".fancybox").fancybox(); 
}); 
</script>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-9" id="mainContent">

        <a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="img/1.jpg"><img src="img/1a.jpg" alt="" /></a>
        <a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="img/me2.jpg"><img src="img/me3.jpg" alt="" /></a>


      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

`
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gMbmzZ

I can't get this fancy box to work for the life of me. I have checked the file path for the css and the javascript and those should be good. I have also made sure to import jquery into my html file.

no matter what i do i can't get it to work. any help is appreicated.